# ios enterprise distribution not installing on another iphone

Tags: ios, distribution, enterprise

Anyone know why I can successfully install my iphone app on my phone via a url with my manifest file for enterprise deployment, but everyone else receives an "Unable to download Application.  could not be installed at this time. Done, Retry" message.  I'm wondering if it's because in my key chain app it shows the Distribution certificate attached to a private key with just my name.  However, my development certificates have a private key called 'IOS Developer and my name". All these Certificates and profiles are confusing me. Could I have attached the wrong private key to this distribution certificate some how?

Comment: are you sure the build being installed on your phone is enterprise and not a debug/develop build?

Comment: I have the same doubt as @calvinBhai.  You can upload the ipa to http://www.testflightapp.com. Testflight can tell you whether it is enterprise build.

Comment: I am specifying the enterprise cert in the build settings for release (and debug to be sure). I'll try to upload it to testflightapp right now.

Comment: also when i install it on my phone it installs the profile that is only attached to my distribution cert...

Comment: yes, testlfight says enterprise.

Comment: any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I used the wrong url to point to the .ipa file.  I was focusing on the certs being the problem.  Any ideas why it allowed me to install it though? Very strange. Thanks tho!